# Am I allowed to post a question to ask for upvotes?

Tags: discussion, reputation, asking-questions, etiquette, upvotes

Is it forbidden to ask users of Stack Overflow to upvote this question, in order to get better reputation? I have tried to find the FAQ section on this site but didn't find it at all.

Comment: why the stackoverflow tag? Did you even read the tag description?

Comment: No I didn't read the tag description

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/begging-for-votes

Comment: A better way of increasing your reputation is by understanding how the site works. Ask quality questions, give quality answers. That includes using the correct tags.

Comment: rep is a function of time and answers; you have only posted 15 answers in one month so there is not a lot of content *or* time for anyone to upvote;  that said, some tags are much harder to get votes in than others.

Comment: I can think of three ways to virtually guarantee one will be downvoted: 1) ask for downvotes; 2) ask not to be downvoted; 3) ask for upvotes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it's not forbidden. But many will see it as rude and useless noise because one of the main mechanism of the entire site network is to vote for things. It's integral in how we interact with the community and, as such, shouldn't need to be mentioned.

Comment: Further, the useless noise will likely be edited out of the question or answer by others in the community.

Comment: Surely it isnt allowed on the main site, though, since it would be off topic, and that is where this question was asked.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Quite so. And will almost invariably result in downvotes instead.

Comment: @mjs Pretty sure OP didn't mean **this** particular question, but in questions in general.

Comment: @mjs I read it to mean asking for votes an _any_ post, not as writing a post specifically to ask for votes. In that case, yes, off topic and downvote to oblivion.

Answer (score -22):

Yes.
However it is not possible to answer just Yes so I have to write more words.

Comment: No, because it is blatantly off topic

Comment: It isn't forbidden, but it will almost guarantee a negative response from the community.